# Django - Mysql Integrity error 1048, "Column 'id_fleet_id' cannot be null"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am getting error like this:

```
1048, "Column 'id_fleet_id' cannot be null"
```

This is my models.py

```
class Fleet(models.Model):
    id_fleet = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id_fleet

class Track(models.Model):
    name_track = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    id_fleet = models.ForeignKey(Fleet)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16,decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    altitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16,decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    length = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16,decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    geom = MultiPointField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_track
```

I try to put `id_fleet = models.ForeignKey(Fleet, null=True, blank=True)` but show error

```
'trackform' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data
```

This is views.py:

```
def add_track(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = TrackForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        p = form.save(commit=False)
        p.save()
        return redirect('map_add.html', pk=p.pk)
else:
    form = TrackForm()
return render(request,'map_add.html', {'form': form}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

This is forms.py:

```
 class TrackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    geom = MultiPointField()

    class Meta:
        model   = Track
        fields  = ('id_fleet','name_track','length', 'geom') 

address = TrackForm()
address.geom = {'type': 'MultiPoint', 'coordinates': [0, 0]}
address.save()
```

can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? the views.py or your forms.py? What's the purpose of the code on your forms.py? If you try to save something with forms without calling is_valid() (like you are doing in the forms.py) it will complain about cleaned_data not existing, because it is created after validation.

Comment: i am getting error in views.py. my forms.py to create data and have field geom use django geojson to create point map use multiplefield. how?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this error raised because you migrate your models when the `id_fleet_id` field `null` parameter was `False` or not set, then later you change value of `null` parameter to `True` but this decision not applied to database, run below commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

And then run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Also you can change **nullable** check in database, open your project database and then open `your_app_name_track` table for edit and check **nullable** of `id_fleet_id` field.